# Copy Data from one SQL Table and Insert it into an other Table

Tags: c#, sql, list

Assume that we have two tables in two databases which are located in different database servers.

**The situation is this**:
*Step 1:* Select data from the first table.
*Step 2:* Iterating over the result of the first step
  *Step 2.1:* For each row that is not present in the socond table
  *Step 2.2:* If the result of *step 2.1* is true, insert the row to the second table.

In case the tables are in same server the following SQL query works fine:

```
INSERT INTO server.table2(id, name, adresse) 
SELECT * FROM server.table1 WHERE table2.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM  server.table2)
```

But I have a problem when the source table and destination table are distributed in two different database servers.

How can I realize the above described steps?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to usually handle this is bulk copy in to a temporary table the data then you can do your normal query like you would.

I don't know your models so I leave it as a experiment to you on how to do that with a List, but if you could open two connections at once you can easily do it like this using SqlBulkCopy to transfer between the two servers.

```
using (var sourceConnection = new SqlConnection(sourceConnectionString))
using (var destinationConnection = new SqlConnection(destinationConnectionString))
{
    sourceConnection.Open();
    destinationConnection.Open();

    var createTableQuery = "create table #t (id uniqueidentifier, name nvarchar(100), adresse(nvarchar(100))";
    using (var createTableCommand = new SqlCommand(createTableQuery, destinationConnection))
    {
        createTableCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    using (var selectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT id, name, adresse FROM table1"))
    using (var selectReader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader())
    using (var destBulkInsert = new SqlBulkCopy(destinationConnection))
    {
        destBulkInsert.DestinationTableName = "#t";
        destBulkInsert.WriteToServer(selectReader);
    }

    var mergeQuery = "INSERT INTO table2(id, name, adresse) SELECT * FROM #t WHERE #t.id NOT IN(SELECT id FROM table2)";
    using (var mergeCommand = new SqlCommand(mergeQuery, destinationConnection))
    {
        mergeCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Scott, Thank you so much for answering my question. I tried like you suggested, bit i got an SqlExeption Error by executing the command ( createTableCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();) the error says : An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in SqlTestConnection.exe

Comment: Use the debugger, [copy the exception details](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saraford/2008/08/07/did-you-know-you-can-copy-the-exception-details-with-one-click-from-the-exception-assistant-276/) as a edit to your question

Answer (score 0):

1. On `server1` create linked server and

   EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'server2', @srvproduct=N'SQL Server'

   EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'server2',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=N'USER_NAME',@rmtpassword='########'
2. Execute your query from `server1` as

   use dbName1
   go

   INSERT INTO server2.dbName2.dbo.table2(id, name, adresse)
   SELECT * FROM dbo.table1 t1
   left join server2.dbName2.dbo.table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id
   where t2.id is null